# Local Notification not firing if the phones time format is 12 hours

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, date-format

Im creating an application which fires a local notification when the time of the day is 2:00pm, I got it working fine when the Date/Time format of my device is set as 24Hours (which returns 14:00). But not when the device Date/Time format is 12Hours. Have i missed something? Here's my code below :

```
public class LocalNotificationsService extends Service {


    final static int RQS_1 = 1;
    static AlarmManager alarmManager;
    static PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    static Calendar calNow;
    static Calendar calSet;

    static Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        context = this;
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            if(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)){
                setAlarm(14, 0);
            }else{
                setAlarm(2, 0);
            }

    }

    public static void setAlarm(int h, int m) {
        calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
            // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocalNotificationsReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, RQS_1, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }

}
```

Comment: is24HourFormat is working properly. Is ur code working for 24 hr format?

Comment: yes @keshav its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its obvious that you wont get notify if time format is changed to 12 hours.

The Problem is with your setAlarm method. You are setting calSet's hour to Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY.

Incase of 12 houre, it has to be Calendar.HOUR.

So please before settting that parameter,check time format of system and set accordingly.

You can ask if you have any further queries :)

Comment: i added this condition inside the setAlarm() method and it worked :)

if(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)){
 calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
}else{
 calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR, h);
}

Thank you i didnt know that haha, I just as i thought, i know i have missed something. Very helpful I learned something new thanks Mr. Jigar Pandya.

Lots of thanks from Philippines :D